# Как изменять прозрачность кнопки или labal-a в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы Labal и кнопка, которая будет на нём постепенно будут становиться прозрачными. Никак не могу понять, как вообще менять прозрачность, что у кнопки, что у Labal-a.

Вот скрин приложения, в нём я обвёл красным Label, который будет постепенно исчезать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак, у виджетов в tkinter нет прозрачности как таковой. Можно менять цвет фона постепенно, пока он не совпадет с цветом фона окна.

Comment: Я вчера этим и занимался, убил огромное количество времени, чтобы постепенно менять цвет Label-a, но или ничего не работало, или жоска лагало.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код